# htaccess rewrite only partially working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using a htaccess rule to rewrite one of my URL’s but it is not working quite how I want it to.

When I point my browser to my new dynamically created URL my htaccess rule switches the request to the old URL (as it should) so the content of the old URL is displayed.  Despite this, the new url has also now changed to the old one.

i.e. I want my browser to display the page information for itemdetails.php?detailed=47 but appear as if it is accessing www.mysite.com/blue-item-e47

My rewrite rule is: RewriteRule ^.*-e([0-9]+)$ /itemdetails.php?detailed=$1 [R]

An example of what is happening at the minute:

1. I point my browser to: www.mysite.com/blue-item-e47
2. My browser switches URL to: itemdetails.php?detailed=47 and displays the page information correctly. Despite this I want the URL to be www.mysite.com/blue-item-e47

Many thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

But the URL rewriter does just that. It basically says to your browser, "You asked for this, now asked me for this as this is where it is now" having sent it a 302 page has moved.

If you didnt want the URL to change, you shouldnt be rewriting it, you would do better to do it within the code of your site

Comment: Just worked out how to fix my problem...i should have been using [L] instead of [R] at the end of my rewrite rule